# Pushing subdocument to parent document array. Only Object_ID gets pushed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm quite new to mongoose. I have found similar questions on here that do answer them, but they are not quite like my problem / I can't find out how it's similar.

I'm trying to push a subdocument into an array on my parent document. Currently I do that like this:
**Upload-soundboard**

```
const multer = require('multer')
const FILE_PATH  = 'uploads'
const passport = require('passport')
const strategy = require('../strategies/strategy')
const upload = multer({
  dest: `${FILE_PATH}/`
})
const { Soundboard } = require('../models/soundboard')
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

passport.use(strategy.jwtStrategy)

router.post('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //console.log(req.body.name)
    req.user.soundboards.push({
      name: req.body.name,
    })
    //console.log(req.user.soundboards)
    await req.user.save()
    res.send('Success!')
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err)
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

This does in fact push a subdocument to the array, but it only adds the Object.ID, and not the name I requested. The schema's look like this:

**USER**

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 255,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 1024
  },
  soundboards: [SoundboardSchema]
}))
```

**SOUNDBOARD**

```
const Soundboard = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  sounds: {
    type: [SoundSchema],
    required: false
  }
})
```

**SOUND**

```
const Sound =  new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  path: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})
```

Does anyone see the answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us more code of the operation part? Where you are trying to push the data.

Comment: hey @Aviv Lo, I will paste the whole file, I updated it in the original post!

Comment: @AvivLo sorry tagged you in the wrong way, see original post.

Comment: Check the answer. But where did you connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should use it instead:

```js
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), async (req, res) => {

    try {

        let newSoundboards = {
            name: req.body.name,
        }

//I don't see you loading your model somewhere with the connection
//So I used yourDB as an example.

        await new yourDB(newSoundboards).save()
        res.send('Success!')
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
    }
})
```

Comment: I am not trying to push something to my database though, I specifically want to add a subdocument to an array, which is on the parent document. I have a document that looks like this in mongodb compass: [pastebin](https://pastebin.pl/view/f60cfa5b) I am not sure if this makes things more clear, if you dont understand what I mean please ask!